# How to see whether a file was opened in universal newlines mode? (Or whatever newline translations it is doing?)

Tags: python, file-io, newline

How can I see if a file-like object is in universal newline mode or not (or any details related to that)?

Both Python 2 and/or 3 answers are okay.

**Hint:** No, the `newlines` attribute does not reflect this. It is always there when the Python interpreter has universal newlines support.

Comment: Can you please explain it more ?

Comment: @Fledgling: which part? Do you know universal newline mode at all?

Comment: This is the default mode and it can be disabled (AFAIK) only during the Python installation.

Comment: Third result in Google for "universal newline python": http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/

Comment: @frostnational: it can be configured for each file (if Python supports it), otherwise it’s always off, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The `mode` attribute is left intact when opening files. I expect you could check if `newlines` exists and `mode` contains `'U'`. Other translations are indicated by `encoding`.

Comment: Seems good for Python2! But for Python3 it’s really deceptive: the file could do the opposite of what the 'U' indicates or not... – I wouldn’t call `encoding` a translation...